# How to update some portion of a td title jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

on ajax success, I have to update some portion of the title.

I am extracting the current td title as:

```
//with this I could get the current td title
let tdTitle = $('.amenity-review-table').find("td[data-unitid='"+resp.unit.id+"']").attr('title');
```

and consoling this tdTitle gives:

```
<div class='unit-title'><strong>Unit: 101</strong></div><span class=''>Washer/Dryer = <span>1</span></span></br><div class='sm-box unit-note-color d-inline-block'></div><span class='unit-note-popup'>note added 3</span>
```

Now, on ajax success I will receive the new updated title and this can be accessed via:
`resp.unit.unit_note`, now once I receive the update I have to update the note shown on the title of td. So, in above case:

I have to update the text inside `unit-note-popup` class to new note which could be received on `resp.unit.note`. So the final title looks like:

```
<div class='unit-title'><strong>Unit: 101</strong></div><span class=''>Washer/Dryer = <span>1</span></span></br><div class='sm-box unit-note-color d-inline-block'></div><span class='unit-note-popup'>"+resp.unit.unit_note+"</span> //my syntax could be wrong here, but this is what I needed
```

Update:
Here, is the jsfiddle to reproduce the scenario:

http://jsfiddle.net/a3t7yfe2/1/

Comment: Are you saying the `title` attribute contains HTML?

Comment: yes, i mean that title attribute

Comment: Is `unit-note-popup` a unique class attribute? Because that is what you basically want, a unique way to identify the element you want to chage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to parse the *HTML* in the `title` attribute into something you can work with (like a `jQuery` object).

Then you can manipulate the `.unit-note-popup` text and write the HTML back into the attribute

```js
// Mock data
const resp = {
  unit: {
    id: 1,
    note: "Note added 4!"
  }
}

const td = $(`.amenity-review-table td[data-unitid="${resp.unit.id}"]`)
const title = td.attr("title")

const titleEl = $(`<div>${title}</div>`) // parse into an element

titleEl.find(".unit-note-popup").text(resp.unit.note)

td.attr("title", titleEl.html())
```

```css
/* Make the title attribute visible */
td[data-unitid]:after {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  content: attr(title);
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="amenity-review-table">
  <tr>
    <td data-unitid="1" title="<div class='unit-title'><strong>Unit: 101</strong></div><span class=''>Washer/Dryer = <span>1</span></span><br/><div class='sm-box unit-note-color d-inline-block'></div><span class='unit-note-popup'>note added 3</span>">
      Check out my super awesome HTML title
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here I've wrapped the `title` HTML text in a `<div>` so that it's encapsulated in a single parent element. That way, you can get the inner HTML back for writing the new value.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong on my case, but I am unable to get this working, could you please check this jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/a3t7yfe2/1/ and make it updated with new title after clicking the button

Comment: my bad it was because of typo of unit-id instead of unitid